# Card Destination URL From Linkedin Carousel Ads

Tags: linkedin-api

We have started using Carousel Ads on LinkedIn, I am having trouble getting some of the attributes for them via the api, one setting in particular is the card destination url which we have set for all of our carousel ads as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOotw.png)

Using the api call:

GET: https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adCreativesV2/{my creative id}

Here is the response (I have replaced all numbers with x):

```
{
"reference": "urn:li:share:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"variables": {
    "data": {
        "com.linkedin.ads.SponsoredUpdateCarouselCreativeVariables": {
            "activity": "urn:li:activity:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "share": "urn:li:share:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "directSponsoredContent": true
        }
    }
},
"changeAuditStamps": {
    "created": {
        "time": xxxxxxxxxxxxx
    },
    "lastModified": {
        "time": xxxxxxxxxxxxx
    }
},
"review": {
    "reviewStatus": "APPROVED"
},
"servingStatuses": [
    "STOPPED"
],
"campaign": "urn:li:sponsoredCampaign:xxxxxxxxx",
"id": xxxxxxxx,
"type": "SPONSORED_UPDATE_CAROUSEL",
"version": {
    "versionTag": "x"
},
"status": "PAUSED"
```

}

The response does not include the main url or any of the individual card destination urls

How can I get the card destination url or main url for carousel ads from the api?

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: could you share more information about the calls you have made to get this result ?

Comment: To get the result above, all I did was enter "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adCreativesV2/{my creative id}" 
Into postman (which is just an API development environment)
Do you need the creative ID that I used? It was the ID of a carousel ad